# Bus Error - What causes this in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, libxml2, libxml-ruby, bus-error

I have run into this error 5 or 10 times over the past few years and have never found a clear answer to this problem.  Here is the error:

```
$ rake db:migrate
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/libxml-ruby-0.9.5/lib/libxml_ruby.bundle: [BUG] Bus Error
ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [i686-darwin9.7.0]

Abort trap
```

The app I am running this in is using RMagick.

I have run into this problem when installing ImageMagick a while ago, and when installing Nokogiri, and when installing MySQL.  For Nokogiri it was because I needed a more recent version of `libxml`.  What are your thoughts on this?  Any fixes?  How can I check the version of RMagick the project is loading?

I am on a Mac, 10.5.8.

Thanks for the help,
Lance

Comment: fixed it by updating libxml-ruby via `sudo gem install libxml-ruby`.  still would like to know a better/reliable fix.

Answer (score 0):

I hit this issue running a worker in resque after upgrading Ruby from 1.8.6 to 1.8.7:

`$ QUEUE=* rake resque:work
(in /Users/kimball/pulse)
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/openssl/ssl-internal.rb:30: [BUG] Bus Error
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [i686-darwin9.8.0]`

Abort trap

Found this, but pretty much just says upgrade to 1.9.1:

http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/show/405

If anyone knows how to fix it in 1.8.7, I'd be grateful.

Kimball